# Substring function crashes app on device (but not on emulator)

Tags: javascript, android

My app works fine in an emulator, but when I install it on a real device it crashes.

After some debugging I found the error was in the sub-string function.

Here's the code that I think is causing problem.

```
if(text.indexOf(" ")>0 && text.indexOf("d")>0) {
            a = text.indexOf(" ");
            b = text.indexOf("d");
        }
        ccs = text.substring(0,a);
        crs = text.substring(a+1,b);
        days = text.substring(b + 1);
```

For example, if text = "30 100d27"; 
ccs = "30", crs = "100" and days = "27"

Why would something like this work as expected on an emulator but crash on a real device?

Comment: Please paste your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try this code in lenovo k900 its working fine.
if you have a doubt then put it into the try block like this.

```
try {
            text = "30 100d27";
            if (text.indexOf(" ") > 0 && text.indexOf("d") > 0) {
                a = text.indexOf(" ");
                b = text.indexOf("d");
            }
            ccs = text.substring(0, a);
            crs = text.substring(a + 1, b);
            days = text.substring(b + 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("mye", "exception " + e);
           }
```

and if your data is like this text = "30100d27" than its gives you **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** so ultimatly check your input.

Comment: Thank you, I tried exception handling and found some exception though none of OutOfBound or NullPointer. But I found what was wrong. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact crash-cause since you haven't provided any error-logs or equal

But i can give you this:

Image a string `"dexample01 "` (a space at the end).

Now run your code an you will run into an exception:

```
text = "dexample01 ";

if (text.indexOf(" ") > 0 && text.indexOf("d") > 0) {
    a = text.indexOf(" "); //a = 9
    b = text.indexOf("d");
}

ccs = text.substring(0,a);
crs = text.substring(a+1,b); // a+1 = 10 -> 10 causes INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS
days = text.substring(b + 1);
```

Maybe you run into this exact special case and because of that your app crashes.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that. Nothing as such.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an example (It uses split() not indexof()):

```
public class Demo3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText edt;
private Button b;
private TextView tv;
private String ccs;
private String crs;
private String days;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo3);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!edt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                String[] split_space = edt.getText().toString().split(" ");
                if(split_space.length==2){
                    ccs = split_space[0];//TODO: check ccs is a number
                    if(!split_space[1].isEmpty()){
                        String[] split_d = split_space[1].split("d");
                        if(split_d.length ==2 ){
                            crs = split_d[0];//TODO: check crs is a number
                            days = split_d[1];//TODO: check days is a number
                        }else{
                           crs = "null";
                           days = "null";
                        }
                    }else{
                        crs = "null";
                        days = "null";
                    }
                }else{
                    ccs = "null";
                    crs = "null";
                    days = "null";
                }
            }else{
                ccs = "null";
                crs = "null";
                days = "null";
            }
            tv.setText("ccs = " + ccs +"---" + "crs = " + crs + "---" + "days = " + days);
        }
    });
}
}
```

demo3.xml:----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edt"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="null"
    android:id="@+id/tv"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/b"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a better alternative.